# Creating a contact in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am creating an app that, in part, creates a contact. I have a layout where the user can enter a name and address using EditText. I have a class called Contact:

```
public class Contact extends Activity{
private String _name, _address, _lat, _lng;
private EditText txtName, txtAddress;

public Contact (String name, String address, String Lat, String Long){
    _name = name;
    _address = address;

}
public String getName(){
    txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.make_Name);
    if (txtName != null)
    {
        _name = txtName.getText().toString();
    }
    return _name;
}

public String getAddress(){
    txtAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.make_Name);
    if (txtAddress != null)
    {
        _address = txtAddress.getText().toString();
    }
    return _address;
}

}
```

The layout has a button that is supposed to get the name and address

```
public class Contacts_Make extends Activity{
private Button make;
Context context;
private Contact contact;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_make);

    make = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make_add);

    make.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                contact.getName();
                Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Throwable e){
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                contact.getAddress();
                Toast.makeText(context, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Throwable e){
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


}
}
```

Every time I push the button my app stops working and I never get any toasts but if I do something like moving to a different layout (known good code) the button works.
Any ideas?

Update:
Thanks @Fahim I changed my code below and I like it better. Now I pass the EditText to the get's and it makes sense to me but it is still not working. I just stops. Oh and I do initialize the contact near the top of the Contacts_Make class then call contact.getName(txtName); contact.getAddress(txtAddress);. Is this right?

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Contacts_Make extends Activity{
private Button back;
private Button make;
private EditText txtName;
private EditText txtAddress;

Context context;
private Contact contact;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.contacts_make);
    
  back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Make_Cancel);
  make = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make_add);
  txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.make_Name);
  txtAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.make_Address);
  
  //Takes you back to the Contacts layout
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Contacts.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
        
        make.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         
            public void onClick(View view) {
             contact.getName(txtName);
             contact.getAddress(txtAddress);


            }
        });
   

 }
}
```

```js
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Contact{
 private String _name, _address, _lat, _lng;
 //private EditText txtName, txtAddress;
 
 public Contact (String name, String address, String Lat, String Long){
  _name = name;
  _address = address;
  _lat = Lat;
  _lng = Long;
 }
 public String getName(EditText name){
  
  if (name != null)
  {
   _name = name.getText().toString();
  }
  return _name;
 }
 
 public String getAddress(EditText address){
  
  if (address != null)
  {
   _address = address.getText().toString();
  }
  return _address;
 }
 public String getLat(){
  return _lat;
 }
 public String getLng(){
  return _lng;
 }
}
```

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776): RunTimeException

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02029d

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2333)

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776):     at android.content.res.Resources.startRC(Resources.java:1059)

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776):     at android.app.ActivityThread$mRunnable.run(ActivityThread.java:2476)

03-13 00:25:28.491: E/Resources(24776):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776): Process: edu.ecpi.myappv3, PID: 24776

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void edu.ecpi.myappv3.Contact.setName(android.widget.EditText)' on a null object reference

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at edu.ecpi.myappv3.Contacts_Make$2.onClick(Contacts_Make.java:53)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5162)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20873)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)

03-13 00:26:03.721: E/AndroidRuntime(24776):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

I am not sure what this error log is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have done following mistakes

1. You have not initialize the contact object and directly call the contact.getname() method. Here this method is throwing NullPointerException.
2. Your class contacts should a normal class, it shouldn't extend Activity. You have to move the edit text code from it to contact_make activity.

Comment: Ok @Fahim I edited my code above to answer the mistakes and it looks right but it is still not working. What's your thoughts?

Comment: Ok I added my error log but it doesn't mean much to me. This is the only part that looks like it might mean something but I am not sure- " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void edu.ecpi.myappv3.Contact.setName(android.widget.EditText)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the Exception raised?

Where do you initialized your `contact` attribute? You're trying to call `.getName()` without having instantiate contact, or some code is missing?

You say that the button works when you move it into another layout. Are you sure the `R.layout.contacts_make` layout have a button identified by `R.id.make_add`?

Comment: The contact is initialized near the top.
Yes the contacts_make layout  does have the button R.id.make_add. When it wasn't working I used code that I know worked to make the button change to a different layout and it worked.

Comment: If you don't see any Toast, I think that either you don't even reach the onClick method or your context is wrong. Can't you simply remove the try/catch and try to use a debugger (see your variable values at runtime or at least see the error you get) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Fahim and everyone for your help. After looking and looking I finaly understood that I had to create a new instants of my Contact class `private Contact contact = new Contact(null, null, null);`. I changed some code around based on some simalare code and got this:

```js
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.widget.EditText;


public class Contact{
 public String _name, _address;
 public LatLng _latlng;
  
 public Contact (String _name, String _address, LatLng _latlng){
  this.setName(_name);
  this.setAddress(_address);
  this.setLatLng(_latlng);
 }
 public String etToSt (EditText _editText){
  String test = _editText.getText().toString();
  return test;
 }
 public void setName(String _name){
  this._name = _name;
  
 }
 public String getName(){
  return _name;
 }
 
 public void setAddress(String _address){
  this._address = _address;
  
 }
 public String getAddress(){
  
  return _address;
  
 }
 public void setLatLng(LatLng _latlng){
  this._latlng = _latlng;
  
 }
 public LatLng getLng(){
  return _latlng;
 }
}
```

Then all I had to add was this code here.

```js
make.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         
            public void onClick(View view) {
             String _name = (String) txtName.getText().toString();
             String _address = (String) txtAddress.getText().toString();
                contact.setName(_name);
             contact.setAddress(_address);
            }
});
```

hope this helps someone else